# Height of the content inside the UIScrollView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, tableview

I know this must exist but I can't seem to find it.  I have a scrollable tableview and I want to find the height of the total tableview beyond the scrollview.  In otherwords...the maxY of the last row on that tableview.  Anyone know how I can do this?

Reason:  I have autodragging feature and I want to stop autodragging when I get to the last item in the table.

Answer or other ideas welcome.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how the `tableview` works. It does not extend beyond the view or height you created. Cells are reused/dequeued so the `tableview` doesn't draw all the cells at once. If you want to determine the last cell, you can check the `indexpath.row` against your datasource count

Answer (score 0):

use this method, to get to the last row of tableview

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let lastElement = dataSource.count - 1
            if indexPath.row == lastElement {
                // now you are on last item.. 
            }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the `willDisplayCell` mentioned by Umer Faroq (which should work as well) would be to use the `ContentSize` and ContentOffset of the TableView. When the `ContentOffset` reaches the ContentSize (or within some buffer you want to use) you'll be at the end of the TableView.